# Problems installing Ubuntu using CD somebody help please

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, wubi

I tried installing Ubuntu 64bit on my new laptop which now has Windows 7 64bit (preinstalled). I want to install Ubuntu and keep Windows 7.

I burned .iso on a CD, I put it in CD drive and rebooted. I saw a keyboard logo and then there was a black empty screen. I take the CD out of the CD drive and turned off using the power button.

I then boot to Windows and ran wubi.exe that was on the disc. I clicked help me run from Live CD (actually it was in Slovenian). Then it finished its job and I rebooted. I got no wubildr stuff and then completing Ubuntu installation. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to see boot options. I added `nomodeset` to normal mode and Ubuntu ran.

But when I clicked **Install Alongside Windows** (in Ubuntu) there was a black screen which told me to remove CD from tray and to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue. I did that and the computer rebooted, and nothing special happened. No installation, I tried again and it didn't worked. Please help.

Comment: Did you immediately get the black screen? Usually this screen comes up at the end of the installation process. To me it looks like you didn't actually install anything. Which Ubuntu-CD are you using?

Answer (score 0):

possible you didnt installed grub in master boot, and win7 boot loader dont see the ubuntu boot loader. Try to edit the win7 boot loader with bcdedit

Comment: how do I do that? What do I need to type into cmd?
bcdedit only lists boot entries

Comment: I think that grub doesn't install if I install alongside windows. Windows bootmanager sees ubuntu, and when I select it, I got no wubildr and then a second later I got completing ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to install ubuntu alongside windows 7 using the wubi installer. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6Ycx2K2OeY&feature=related do it this way just to avoid boot or partitions issues.